# Use the Azure Cli to access Azure storage using a SAS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

Is there a way of using a SAS (shared access signature) to access an Azure storage container from the CLI?

It's clearly possible [using an account name and a key](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/), or using a connection string. But I want to use the CLI in a script that should only be able to read from a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to list blobs with sas (via `--sas` command line parameter) has been around for a while.

The latest CLI (0.10.2) now has a `--sas` command line option when uploading/downloading blobs as well. So...

```
azure storage blob upload --sas <sas> -c <connection-string> ...
azure storage blob list --sas <sas> ...
azure storage blob download --sas <sas> ...
```

Comment: Future readers - note that the `--sas` argument takes only the sas parameters and signatures. Not the whole uri. Also, the sas contains characters that have to be escaped in some cases (`%`,`&` etc). Make sure you do that.

Answer (score 3):

In newest versions of Azure CLI:

```
az storage blob upload --connection-string "<your SAS connection string>"
az storage blob list --connection-string "<your SAS connection string>"
az storage blob download --connection-string "<your SAS connection string>"
```